# Functional Interface accepting Stream or Optional?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, functional-interface

I want to create a `@FunctionalInterface` in Java which accepts both `Stream`s or `Optional` types as a parameter. I tried to do this, but since they don't share a common interface it seems impossible to achieve. I also tried using a common wrapper class which invokes the `@FunctionalInterface` but since I need the type parameters at runtime it seems this isn't possible.

Minimum example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface AcceptingInterface<S, T> {

    T accept(S s);

}
```

---

```
public class Test<S, T> {

    private final AcceptingInterface<S, T> funcInterface;

    private final Class<S> source;

    private final Class<T> target;

    public Test(AcceptingInterface<S, T> a, Class<S> s, Class<T> t) {
        this.funcInterface = a;
        this.source = s;
        this.target = t;
    }

    public T invoke(S s) {
        return s == null ? null : this.funcInterface.accept(s);
    }

    public Class<S> getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public Class<T> getTarget() {
        return target;
    }
}
```

Maybe my approach is wrong... I would love to receive feedback and/or a solution to this problem.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to implement, but you seem to have to use the adapter pattern to make these two align with your functional interface.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Thanks for the input, maybe that's the way to go and I'll try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to treat an Optional as a Stream of 0-1 elements, in which case you can add a default method that translates from Optional to Stream, thusly:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface AcceptingInterface<V, T> {

    T accept(Stream<? extends V> s); 
    default T accept(Optional<? extends V> opt){
        return accept(opt.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)); 
    }

}
```

Java 9 is supposed to add an `Optional.stream()` method.

Comment: Seems like a fair approach. Let's see if I can get this to work with the above proposed adapter pattern.

Comment: @AlexvandenHoogen gustafc's answer really _adapts_ optional to stream. This is what I was talking about earlier: you might adapt both `Stream` and `Optional` to a _common_ type, and this answer just adapts _both_ `Stream` and `Optional` to `Stream`. This is a perfect example/answer.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but it is with the return type. So I cannot use method overloading. Seems the ```sealed``` interfaces (in preview atm) will help me.